# Size of database . PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, size

I want to know the size of my database using php. 
How to display the size in megabytes entire database? Size in megabytes a specific request?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this to get the size in bytes:

```
mysql_select_db("yourdatabase");  
$q = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS");  
$size = 0;  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {  
    $size += $row["Data_length"] + $row["Index_length"];  
}
```

then to convert in megabytes:

```
$decimals = 2;  
$mbytes = number_format($size/(1024*1024),$decimals);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name",
sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 /
1024 "Data Base Size in MB",
sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

Answer (score 3):

I try to modify from internet source for this case, just try it please.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","password here"); 
 $namadb=''; //put db name here

 $sql="SELECT table_schema 'db_name', SUM( data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 'db_size_in_mb' FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema='$namadb' GROUP BY table_schema ;";
 $query=mysql_query($sql);
 $data=mysql_fetch_array($query); 
 print $data['db_size_in_mb'];
```

Answer (score 2):

This query give you a useful data about your database size:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_SCHEMA AS DB_Name, 
    count(TABLE_SCHEMA) AS Total_Tables, 
    SUM(TABLE_ROWS) AS Total_Tables_Row, 
    ROUND(sum(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024) AS "DB Size (MB)",
    ROUND(sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024) AS "Free Space (MB)"
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA ;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try querying `information_schema`.